# List contenttype do not inherit the contenttype from website after adding new columns

Tags: list, content-type, inheritance

I am using sp 2010. I have a list with for example contenttype "Project portal". I have add some new columns to this contenttype on website level. I can see these new columns on website content level. But I do not see them on the contenttype on list level. Why do they not inherited the new columns from the parent?

Here is the powershell script for the creation of the new columns:

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://myCompany.net/teams/siterequests" 
$web = $site.RootWeb   
$ct = $web.ContentTypes["Project portal"]

$fieldname = "srConsultingEngineer"
$displayname = "Consulting Engineer"
$fieldXML = "<Field Type='Note'  Name='" + $fieldname + "'  Description=''  DisplayName='" + $displayname + "'  Group='Site Request Columns'  Hidden='FALSE' Required='FALSE'  ShowInDisplayForm='TRUE'  ShowInEditForm='TRUE'  ShowInListSettings='TRUE'  ShowInNewForm='TRUE'></Field>"  
$web.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($fieldXML) 
"get created column"
$field = $web.fields.getfield("srConsultingEngineer")
"set group of field"
$field.Group = "Site Request Columns"
"create field link"
$fieldLink = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLink($field)
"connect fieldlink to contenttype"
$ct.fieldlinks.add($fieldLink)
$ct.update()
```

This is the website contenttype. Here my new column is available and the inherti option is TRUE.
[image]

This is the contenttype on the list. Here you do not see the column.
[image]

What is my issue? Is my powershell script not OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pushing changes to the children you should specify as

```
$ct.update($true)
```

See the function signature http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms475130%28v=office.15%29.aspx